# Trouble optimizing python interpolation script

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am interpolating arrival times for some public transportation data I have. I have a working script, but it seems to be running in quadratic time. Here is the script:

```
import pandas as pd

#read the txt file
st = pd.read_csv('interpolated_test.csv')

# sort first by trip_id, then by stop_sequence
sorted_st = st.sort(['trip_id','stop_sequence'], ascending=[False,True])

# reset the index values in prep. for iteration
reindexed = sorted_st.reset_index(drop=True)

# for each row in 'arrival_time' that has a value of hh:mm:ss
for i in reindexed['arrival_time']:
# for i in range(len(reindexed['arrival_time'])):
    if pd.isnull(i) == False:
        # splice hh:mm:ss
        hour = int(i[:2])
        minute = int(i[3:5])
        # assign hh:mm:ss to numeric value
        minute_value = (hour * 60) + minute

        # replace current string with int value
        # takes ~655s to execute on Macbook Pro w/ entire stop_times.txt
        # runs in quadratic time
        reindexed = reindexed.replace(i,minute_value)

# interpolate and write out
new = reindexed.apply(pd.Series.interpolate)
print(new)
```

Here is a link to the csv: https://gist.github.com/adampitchie/0192933ed0eba122ba7e

I shortened the csv so you can run the file without waiting for it to finish.

This should be low-hanging fruit for anybody familiar with pandas, but I'm stuck and any help would be appreciated.

**[UPDATE]**
So I tried running the same code with the [FULL CSV FILE](https://gist.github.com/adampitchie/d17e010f61904701358c), and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tester/Desktop/ETL/interpolate.py", line 49, in <module>
    reindexed[col].dt.hour * 60
  File "pandas/src/properties.pyx", line 34, in pandas.lib.cache_readonly.__get__ (pandas/lib.c:40664)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2513, in dt
    raise TypeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values")
TypeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

It looks like `pd.to_datetime(reindexed[col])` is not working.
Here is the code, for the sake of completedness:

```
import pandas as pd

st = pd.read_csv('csv/stop_times.csv')

sorted_st = st.sort(['trip_id','stop_sequence'], ascending=[False,True])

reindexed = sorted_st.reset_index(drop=True)

for col in ('arrival_time', 'departure_time'):
    reindexed[col] = pd.to_datetime(reindexed[col])
    reindexed[col] = (
        reindexed[col].dt.hour * 60
        + reindexed[col].dt.minute)
    reindexed[col] = reindexed[col].interpolate()

print(reindexed.iloc[:, :3])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you can, try to phrase computations as operations on whole columns rather than rows, or item-by-item. Instead of handling each value in `reindexed['arrival_time']` one at a time, you can convert the whole column into `datetime64`s using `pd.to_datetime`. A Series of `datetime64`s has a `dt` attribute which allows you to access the hour and minutes as integers. So you can express the calculation for the whole column like this:

```
for col in ('arrival_time', 'departure_time'):
    reindexed[col] = pd.to_datetime(reindexed[col])
    reindexed[col] = (
        reindexed[col].dt.hour * 60
        + reindexed[col].dt.minute)
    reindexed[col] = reindexed[col].interpolate()

print(reindexed.iloc[:5, :3])
```

yields

```
    trip_id  arrival_time  departure_time
0   1423492    647.000000      647.000000
1   1423492    649.666667      649.666667
2   1423492    652.333333      652.333333
3   1423492    655.000000      655.000000
4   1423492    655.750000      655.750000
```

---

**Debugging `TypeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`**:

Indeed, as you pointed out, `pd.to_datetime` is not converting the times to datetime64s. Instead, it is
just returning the same data as strings. `pd.to_datetime` returns the input when it encounters an error trying to convert the input to datetimes. You can gather a bit more information about what is going wrong by adding the `errors='raise'` parameter:

```
pd.to_datetime(reindexed['arrival_time'], errors='raise')
```

raises

```
ValueError: hour must be in 0..23
```

So aha -- the time format probably has times whose hours exceed 23.

Using

```
col = 'arrival_time'
x = reindexed[col]
mask = x.str.extract(r'(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)')[0].astype('int')  > 23
```

we can see examples of rows where the hours is greater than 23:

```
In [48]: x[mask].head()
Out[48]: 
42605    26:09:00
42610    26:12:00
42611    26:20:00
42612    26:30:00
42613    26:35:00
Name: arrival_time, dtype: object
```

The [x.str.extract](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#extracting-substrings) splits the arrival time strings using the regex pattern
`r'(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)'`. It returns a DataFrame with three columns.

This piece of debugging code suggests a workaround. Instead of `pd.to_datetime`, 
we could use `x.str.extract` to find the hours and minutes:

```
import pandas as pd

st = pd.read_csv('csv/stop_times.csv')

sorted_st = st.sort(['trip_id','stop_sequence'], ascending=[False,True])

reindexed = sorted_st.reset_index(drop=True)

for col in ('arrival_time', 'departure_time'):
    df = reindexed[col].str.extract(
        r'(?P<hour>\d+):(?P<minute>\d+):(?P<second>\d+)').astype('float')
    reindexed[col] = df['hour'] * 60 + df['minute']
    reindexed[col] = reindexed[col].interpolate()

print(reindexed.iloc[:5, :3])
```

yields

```
   trip_id  arrival_time  departure_time
0  1423492    647.000000      647.000000
1  1423492    649.666667      649.666667
2  1423492    652.333333      652.333333
3  1423492    655.000000      655.000000
4  1423492    655.750000      655.750000
```

Comment: So that seems to work for the values that exist, but seems to assign a value of -61 for all empty spaces/null values and doesn't interpolate between the actual values.

Comment: Upon further inspection, whenever pd.to_datetime() is called, it's replacing all NaNs with NaTs, which seems to cause interpolate to fail. However, I still can't get interpolate to work.

Comment: I've posted the result I'm getting. Is that not what you are seeing?

Comment: So I did `sudo pip install --upgrade pandas`, and behold, interpolation works as you suggested. Also, thank you for the best practices. I appreciate it!

Comment: I've added some comments on how to debug the error, why the error occurs and a workaround.

Comment: Bravo! You've been very helpful!

Comment: I have a follow up question: Any idea how I might convert back into HH:MM:SS format once the values are interpolated?

Comment: Since the goal of stackoverflow is to make a searchable archive of good questions paired with good answers, let's make this in a new question.

Comment: Understood. [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233146/convert-columns-of-time-in-minutes-format-to-time-in-hhmmss-format-in-pandas) is a link to the new question.