# Convert columns of time in minutes format to time in HH:MM:SS format in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am using a script to interpolate stop times from the format HH:MM:SS into minute int values. The script is as follows.

```
# read in new csv file
reindexed = pd.read_csv('output/stop_times.csv')

for col in ('arrival_time', 'departure_time'):
    # extract hh:mm:ss values
    df = reindexed[col].str.extract(
        r'(?P<hour>\d+):(?P<minute>\d+):(?P<second>\d+)').astype('float')
    # convert to int value
    reindexed[col] = df['hour'] * 60 + df['minute']
    # interpolate
    reindexed[col] = reindexed[col].interpolate()
    reindexed[col] = np.round(reindexed[col], decimals=2)
    reindexed.to_csv('output/stop_times.csv', index=False)

# convert minutes back to HH:MM:SS
```

What I would now like is to convert those values back into a HH:MM:SS format, but I am having trouble figuring that out. I have a hunch that the method is hidden somewhere in the [timeseries documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html), but I have come up short of a result.

Here is a sample CSV derived from the larger stop_times.csv file that I am using. The **arrival_time** and **departure_time** columns are of focus:

```
stop_id,stop_code,stop_name,stop_desc,stop_lat,stop_lon,location_type,parent_station,trip_id,arrival_time,departure_time,stop_sequence,pickup_type,drop_off_type,stop_headsign
02303,02303,LCC Station Bay C,lcc_c,44.00981229999999,-123.0351463,,99994.0,1475360,707.0,707.0,1,0,0,82 EUGENE STATION
01092,01092,N/S of 30th E of University,,44.0242826,-123.07484540000002,,,1475360,709.67,709.67,2,0,0,82 EUGENE STATION
01089,01089,N/S of 30th W of Alder,,44.0242545,-123.08092409999999,,,1475360,712.33,712.33,3,0,0,82 EUGENE STATION
01409,01409,"Amazon Station, Bay A",amz_a,44.026660799999995,-123.08448870000001,,99993.0,1475360,715.0,715.0,4,0,0,82 EUGENE STATION
01222,01222,E/S of Amazon Prkwy N of 24th,,44.0339371,-123.0887632,,,1475360,715.75,715.75,5,0,0,82 EUGENE STATION
01548,01548,E/S of Amazon Pkwy S of 19th,,44.038014700000005,-123.0896553,,,1475360,716.5,716.5,6,0,0,82 EUGENE STATION
```

Here is a reference for deriving HH:MM:SS values from a time value in minutes:

```
78.6 minutes can be converted to hours by dividing 78.6 minutes / 60 minutes/hour = 1.31 hours
1.31 hours can be broken down to 1 hour plus 0.31 hours - 1 hour
0.31 hours * 60 minutes/hour = 18.6 minutes - 18 minutes
0.6 minutes * 60 seconds/minute = 36 seconds - 36 seconds
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Per the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27454325/190597), perhaps
the best thing to do would be to keep the original HH:MM:SS strings:

So instead of

```
for col in ('arrival_time', 'departure_time'):
    df = reindexed[col].str.extract(
        r'(?P<hour>\d+):(?P<minute>\d+):(?P<second>\d+)').astype('float')
    reindexed[col] = df['hour'] * 60 + df['minute']
```

use

```
for col in ('arrival_time', 'departure_time'):
    newcol = '{}_minutes'.format(col)
    df = reindexed[col].str.extract(
        r'(?P<hour>\d+):(?P<minute>\d+):(?P<second>\d+)').astype('float')
    reindexed[newcol] = df['hour'] * 60 + df['minute']
```

Then you don't have to do any new calculations to recover the HH:MM:SS strings.
`reindexed['arrival_time']`  will still be the original HH:MM:SS strings, and 
`reindexed['arrival_time_minutes']`  would be the time duration in minutes.

---

Building on [Jianxun Li's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31234100/190597),
to chop off the microseconds, you could multiply the minutes by 60 and then call `astype(int)`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3) * 1000, columns=['minutes'])
df['HH:MM:SS'] = pd.to_timedelta((60*df['minutes']).astype('int'), unit='s')
```

which yields

```
      minutes  HH:MM:SS
0  548.813504  09:08:48
1  715.189366  11:55:11
2  602.763376  10:02:45
```

Note that the `df['HH:MM:SS']` column contains `pd.Timedelta`s:

```
In [240]: df['HH:MM:SS'].iloc[0]
Out[240]: Timedelta('0 days 09:08:48')
```

However, if you try to store this data in a csv

```
In [223]: df.to_csv('/tmp/out', date_format='%H:%M:%S')
```

you get:

```
,minutes,HH:MM:SS
0,548.813503927,0 days 09:08:48.000000000
1,715.189366372,0 days 11:55:11.000000000
2,602.763376072,0 days 10:02:45.000000000
```

If the minute values are too big, you would also see `days` as part of the timedelta string representation:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3) * 10000, columns=['minutes'])
df['HH:MM:SS'] = pd.to_timedelta((60*df['minutes']).astype('int'), unit='s')
```

yields

```
       minutes        HH:MM:SS
0  5488.135039 3 days 19:28:08
1  7151.893664 4 days 23:11:53
2  6027.633761 4 days 04:27:38
```

That might not be what you want. In that case, instead of

```
df['HH:MM:SS'] = pd.to_timedelta((60*df['minutes']).astype('int'), unit='s')
```

per [Phillip Cloud's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19106012/190597) you could use

```
import operator
fmt = operator.methodcaller('strftime', '%H:%M:%S')
df['HH:MM:SS'] = pd.to_datetime(df['minutes'], unit='m').map(fmt)
```

The result looks the same, but now the `df['HH:MM:SS']` column contains *strings*

```
In [244]: df['HH:MM:SS'].iloc[0]
Out[244]: '09:08:48'
```

Note that this chops off (omits) both the whole days and the microseconds.
Writing the DataFrame to a CSV

```
In [229]: df.to_csv('/tmp/out', date_format='%H:%M:%S')
```

now yields

```
,minutes,HH:MM:SS
0,548.813503927,09:08:48
1,715.189366372,11:55:11
2,602.763376072,10:02:45
```

Comment: Thanks, both of the answers are correct, but since @HappyLeapSecond is more complete I chose it as the best answer to the question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider using `pd.to_timedelta`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10) * 1000, columns=['time_in_minutes'])

Out[94]: 
   time_in_minutes
0         548.8135
1         715.1894
2         602.7634
3         544.8832
4         423.6548
5         645.8941
6         437.5872
7         891.7730
8         963.6628
9         383.4415

# As Jeff suggests, pd.to_timedelta is a very handy tool to do this
df['time_delta'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.time_in_minutes, unit='m')


Out[96]: 
   time_in_minutes      time_delta
0         548.8135 09:08:48.810235
1         715.1894 11:55:11.361982
2         602.7634 10:02:45.802564
3         544.8832 09:04:52.990979
4         423.6548 07:03:39.287960
5         645.8941 10:45:53.646784
6         437.5872 07:17:35.232675
7         891.7730 14:51:46.380046
8         963.6628 16:03:39.765630
9         383.4415 06:23:26.491129
```

Comment: u can directly do this with to_timedelta(..., unit='m')

Comment: @Jeff Thanks, Jeff. I wasn't aware of the `to_timedelta()` functionality. It's certainly much better what I wrote. I'll modify the code shortly.